# Meteor - for what reason were all my packages removed?

Tags: meteor, package

On my local machine I'm working on a Meteor project. I left the Terminal on and when I came back home I checked and saw what's in the code below (first line was from yesterday). I fixed the problem by copy pasting it and then did some converting so I could add all the packages back. Simply by using 'meteor add ...'. Anyone has any clue how this can happen? Just imagine if your production server decided to delete all meteor packages ;)

```
=> Client modified -- refreshing (x26)

Changes to your project's package version selections:

accounts-base              removed from your project
accounts-facebook          removed from your project
accounts-oauth             removed from your project
accounts-twitter           removed from your project
accounts-ui-unstyled       removed from your project
application-configuration  removed from your project
autopublish                removed from your project
autoupdate                 removed from your project
base64                     removed from your project
binary-heap                removed from your project
blaze                      removed from your project
blaze-tools                removed from your project
boilerplate-generator      removed from your project
callback-hook              removed from your project
check                      removed from your project
ddp                        removed from your project
deps                       removed from your project
ejson                      removed from your project
facebook                   removed from your project
fastclick                  removed from your project
follower-livedata          removed from your project
fourseven:scss             removed from your project
geojson-utils              removed from your project
html-tools                 removed from your project
htmljs                     removed from your project
http                       removed from your project
id-map                     removed from your project
insecure                   removed from your project
iron:controller            removed from your project
iron:core                  removed from your project
iron:dynamic-template      removed from your project
iron:layout                removed from your project
iron:location              removed from your project
iron:middleware-stack      removed from your project
iron:router                removed from your project
iron:url                   removed from your project
jquery                     removed from your project
json                       removed from your project
launch-screen              removed from your project
livedata                   removed from your project
localstorage               removed from your project
logging                    removed from your project
meteor                     removed from your project
meteor-platform            removed from your project
minifiers                  removed from your project
minimongo                  removed from your project
mobile-status-bar          removed from your project
mongo                      removed from your project
oauth                      removed from your project
oauth1                     removed from your project
oauth2                     removed from your project
observe-sequence           removed from your project
ordered-dict               removed from your project
random                     removed from your project
reactive-dict              removed from your project
reactive-var               removed from your project
reload                     removed from your project
retry                      removed from your project
routepolicy                removed from your project
sacha:spin                 removed from your project
sergeyt:typeahead          removed from your project
service-configuration      removed from your project
session                    removed from your project
spacebars                  removed from your project
spacebars-compiler         removed from your project
templating                 removed from your project
tracker                    removed from your project
twitter                    removed from your project
ui                         removed from your project
underscore                 removed from your project
url                        removed from your project
webapp                     removed from your project
webapp-hashing             removed from your project

W20150301-17:54:20.272(1)? (STDERR)
W20150301-17:54:20.273(1)? (STDERR) /Users/flowen/Documents/_htdocs/dateanomad.net/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:246
W20150301-17:54:20.274(1)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20150301-17:54:20.274(1)? (STDERR)    ^
W20150301-17:54:20.275(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
W20150301-17:54:20.275(1)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/collections.js:1:51
W20150301-17:54:20.275(1)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/collections.js:4:3
W20150301-17:54:20.275(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/flowen/Documents/_htdocs/dateanomad.net/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
W20150301-17:54:20.276(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150301-17:54:20.276(1)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/flowen/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.11tnnrw++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150301-17:54:20.276(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/flowen/Documents/_htdocs/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:116:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact scenario can happen if your meteor app is running then the `.meteor` directory is removed or more specifically the `.meteor/packages` file is deleted.

You can check this by creating a test project using `meteor create`, then running it via `meteor run` and deleting the `.meteor/packages` file.

I'm not too sure what could have caused the file to be deleted, though.

This can't happen in production mode/meteor deploy because it wouldn't file watch. Something on your machine deleted the file.

Comment: very odd it happened! Thanks for the explanation about production mode!